# how to check if my string contain text?

Tags: c#, winforms

if i have this string:

`12345`  =  `true`

`123a45` =  `false`

`abcde`  =  `false`

how to do it in C#?

Comment: Do you just wish to verify, that your string is a number? If so, use `int.TryParse(string yourString)` as mentioned in the answers. Or do you want to check if your string matches the exact string `12345`? Then use `"12345".Equals(string yourString)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Regex.IsMatch(sinput,@"\d+");
```

to match a string containing just digits.
If you forgot an optional digit in the question, 
use this:

```
Regex.IsMatch("+12345", @"[+-]?\d+");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid RegEx, then you can use the built-in `char` methods:

```
bool allDigits = s.All(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

[int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) or long.TryParse.

You can also use Regex for any length of number:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "^[0-9]+$"))
// ...
```

Comment: Not good - what about `74694369464684964894684684482347357585787897489478777676`?

Answer (score 0):

```
int myNumber;
if( int.TryParse(myString, out myNumber) == true )
{
 // is a number and myNumber contains it
}
else
{
 // isn't a number
}
```

if it's a BIG number, use long or double or.... instead of int.

Comment: -1 for same reason as comment on HuBeZa answer - even double can't store really long string of digits and even so, it allows "." which is not a digit.

Comment: @Shadow: right you are. If all you want is validation, and not conversion, regular expression is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for checking only letters in string in C#. You can modify it upto your need.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string MyString = "A @string & and 2.";

            Console.WriteLine(MyString);
            for (int charpos = 0; charpos < MyString.Length; charpos++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Char.IsLetter(MyString, charpos));    
            }
            //Keep the console on screen
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool ContainsText(string input)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (((int) input[i] >= 65 && (int) input[i] <= 90) || ((int) input[i] >= 97 && (int) input[i] <= 177))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Running:

```
MessageBox.Show(ContainsText("abc").ToString());
MessageBox.Show(ContainsText("123").ToString());
MessageBox.Show(ContainsText("123b23").ToString());
```

returns True, False, True respectively

Comment: I think that he means "non digit character" by *text*

Comment: You solution is not complete. You are supposing that encoding is permament